# Disable auto indent globally in Emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation, auto-indent

How to disable auto indent in Emacs globally or only for some modes?

I have a number of packages installed for RubyOnRails (ruby, html, js, css).

Let's say I want to disable autoindent for css-mode.

Comment: There is no auto indent by default. I think you should clarify your question first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look for variable names containing the word `electric`. (This is the common Emacs parlance for actions which occur automatically when particular visible characters are typed.)

In this instance, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `electric` <kbd>RET</kbd> shows me that there is a `css-electric-keys` variable containing a list of "Self inserting keys which should trigger re-indentation."

You could use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `css-electric-keys` <kbd>RET</kbd> to set this list to nil, or add `(setq css-electric-keys nil)` to your init file.

Sometimes a minor mode is used to implement electric behaviours, so that you can switch them on and off more easily. Those would likely be found via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-command` <kbd>RET</kbd> `electric` <kbd>RET</kbd>, and you would probably use a major mode hook to ensure that the electric minor mode was disabled, in a similar fashion to this:

```
(add-hook 'MAJORMODE-mode-hook 'my-MAJORMODE-mode-hook)
(defun my-MAJORMODE-mode-hook ()
  (ELECTRICMODE-mode 0))
```

Comment: How do you find out what terms to use in your last ELECTRICMODE-mode example?  I'm having trouble turning off autoindenting in JavaScript files and I haven't had any luck with your other suggestions for JS, unfortunately.

Comment: My best suggestion is to get as familiar as you can with the self-documenting nature of Emacs, and commands which revolve around this facility. For javascript mode I used `M-x find-function RET javascript-mode RET` to open the source file which defines it, and then simply searched for "auto" and quickly found an appropriate hit in this variable: `C-h v js-auto-indent-flag RET` (which happens to be customizable, so you could also have found it by using `M-x customize-group RET js RET` ("javascript" would have been nicer, but "js" was a fairly obvious second-guess).

Comment: Similarly, `M-x apropos-variable RET indent RET` would (after the mode was loaded) discover the `js-auto-indent-flag` variable. As a general recommendation, you may find it useful to read through the manual's section on Help: `M-: (info "(emacs) Help") RET`. Once you have a decent handle on how to find things like this, customisation becomes a much easier process.

Answer (score 8):

For me, on emacs 24.x, <kbd>M-x</kbd>`electric-indent-mode` toggled the behavior that I wanted to disable.

FWIW, the behavior was that <kbd>RET</kbd> was bound to the command `newline` which is defined in `simple.el`...  Among other things, the behavior of that command is altered by `electric-indent-mode`.

Comment: Next time my enter key doesn't do what I want, I'll remember to just `C-h k RET` to see what function/command it is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (TypeScript + React through web-mode) the variable causing indent on `RET` was `web-mode-enable-auto-indentation` - had to toggle it from `t` to `nil`.

I guess, in general you may probably want to check all variables with `indent` in their names that are `t`. Or rather start looking from `RET` binding as others suggest.