# Turn off auto-indent in perl-mode emacs

Tags: emacs, cygwin, elisp, indentation, cperl-mode

When I use Emacs, I turn of any auto indentation and use a custom indentation scheme (keep indentation of previous line, only using spaces).

In c-mode I just used `C-c C-l` to turn off electric mode.

But in perl-mode I'm not sure how to achieve the same.

Looking at http://mirror.fraunhofer.de/CPAN/misc/emacs/perl-mode.el . I can see

```
(defvar perl-mode-map ()
  "Keymap used in Perl mode.")
(if perl-mode-map
    ()
  (setq perl-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))
  (define-key perl-mode-map "{" 'electric-perl-terminator)
  (define-key perl-mode-map "}" 'electric-perl-terminator)
  (define-key perl-mode-map ";" 'electric-perl-terminator)
  ...
```

So I tried `M-x set-variable perl-mode-map`, but I only get `[No match]`.

Is this because my perl-mode.el is precompiled? When I try to `M-x find-function perl-mode` it complains that it can't find it perl-mode.el . I do however have a perl-mode.elc file though.

I am running emacs through a console on cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.I didn't realise there were normal variables and user option variables in emacs.

Running `(setq perl-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))` in the scratch buffer then reloading perl-mode disabled the electric indentation for me.

Also, thanks for the answer syohex.

EDIT: **It is important to reload perl-mode for this to work.**

Answer (score 2):

Add following code your configuration file(.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el)

```
(defun perl-mode-disable-auto-indent ()
  (local-unset-key (kbd "{"))
  (local-unset-key (kbd "}"))
  (local-unset-key (kbd ";"))
  (local-unset-key (kbd ":")))

(add-hook 'perl-mode-hook 'perl-mode-disable-auto-indent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `electric-indent-mode` for `perl-mode` is how I do it. I add the following in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(defun perl-mode-disable-auto-indent()
    (electric-indent-mode -1))
(add-hook 'perl-mode-hook 'perl-mode-disable-auto-indent)
```

You can find similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718310/emacs-version-24-4-new-obnoxious-loss-of-indentation-on-hitting-return), [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/how-to-disable-auto-indentation-of-new-lines), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390238/disable-auto-indent-globally-in-emacs)