# Emacs version 24.4: New obnoxious loss of indentation on hitting RETURN

Tags: emacs, indentation

Starting with Emacs 24.4, when I type a line beginning with white space (a typical way to
denote a new paragraph) and at the end of it I hit RETURN, the white space disappears.
  This problem appears also with 'emacs -Q'.
  My .emacs file uses a rather plain text-mode paragraphing scheme, namely,

```
(setq default-major-mode 'text-mode)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'paragraph-indent-minor-mode)
```

which has been working without problems for a dozen years. The bug appeared when I installed the current (24.4) version.

Basically, I type:

```
   This is a line beginning with four spaces
```

and as soon as I type RETURN my line immediately becomes

```
This is a line beginning with four spaces
```

That is, the indentation vanishes. I'd much appreciate some advice.
Should I post a bug?

Comment: Absolutely `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: You have correctly identified this annoyance, er, shiny new feature! I do this in my init file: `(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))`. That works with any Emacs version.

Answer (score 6):

In Emacs 24.4, `electric-indent-mode` is enabled by default.  It seems like that's what's causing this problem in combination with `paragraph-indent-minor-mode`.  You can avoid that by turning off Electric Indent mode everywhere (`M-x electric-indent-mode`) or just in the local buffer (`M-x electric-indent-local-mode`).

Answer (score 1):

The following will try to keep `electric-indent-mode` from stepping on the toes of `paragraph-indent-minor-mode`. It doesn't attempt to be robust in all situations, but I suspect it's entirely sufficient in your situation.

```el
(defvar-local my-local-electric-indent-status :unknown)

(defun my-local-electric-indent-disable ()
  "Make `electric-indent-mode' ineffective in the current buffer."
  (setq my-local-electric-indent-status electric-indent-mode)
  (electric-indent-local-mode -1))

(defun my-local-electric-indent-restore ()
  "Restore original status of `electric-indent-mode' in the current buffer."
  (unless (eq my-local-electric-indent-status :unknown)
    (electric-indent-local-mode my-local-electric-indent-status)))

(add-hook 'paragraph-indent-minor-mode-on-hook #'my-local-electric-indent-disable)
(add-hook 'paragraph-indent-minor-mode-off-hook #'my-local-electric-indent-restore)
```

If you're not running at least Emacs 24.3, replace the `defvar-local` with:

```el
(defvar my-local-electric-indent-status :unknown)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-local-electric-indent-status)
```

Answer (score -1):

;;(global-set-key "\em" 'newline) ;;for emacs 23

global-set-key "\em" 'electric-newline-and-maybe-indent) ;;for emacs 24