# Get back behaviour of C-j from older version of Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

### Not a duplicate of [Emacs version 24.4: New obnoxious loss of indentation on hitting RETURN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718310/)

Turning off `electric-indent-mode` doesn't solve the issues I am having. Notice that that question doesn't have an accepted answer.

### Original question:

Currently using Emacs version 24.5.1 on Windows 7, and the changed behaviour of `C-j` is extremely irritating.  I am sure the designers must have thought it a good idea, but I don't.

Is there any way to get back the behaviour of `C-j` from older versions? More specifically, I am thinking of v21.x (installed it a few years back on my Mac).

#### Explanation:

This is what I get in my older version (imagine hitting `C-j` at the end of each line:

```
Line 01:    Some text.
Line 02:    Some more text.
Line 03:
Line 04:    Yet more text (notice the indentation stays the same despite
Line 05:    the empty line in-between).
```

In 24.5.1 by default I get (again imagine hitting `C-j` at the end of each line):

```
Line 01:    Some text.
Line 02:    Some more text.
Line 03:
Line 04: Yet more text (notice the indentation goes to zero because of
Line 05: the empty line in-between).
```

The key binding `C-j` runs `newline-and-indent` in Emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: Do you have an older version where you can just copy the functions over to your new `.emacs` file and change the keyboard shortcut to the slightly modified name for the older version?

Comment: @lawlist I've added an explanation above. Hopefully it's understandable :-).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the built in function `default-indent-new-line`. Try it by `M-x default-indent-new-line`. At least in `text-mode` it does what you describe.

To overwrite `C-j` in every mode you can just use this snippet in your .emacs file.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-j")  'default-indent-new-line)
```

Comment: Seems to work the same way as `newline-and-indent`, so doesn't solve my problem.