# Disable auto indentation in Emacs on Windows

Tags: windows, emacs, prolog, indentation, auto-indent

I'm currently using emacs-25.3_1 and using emacs to edit prolog files. The end of every line ends with '.' instead of a ';' so emacs auto indents my lines. I've been looking up how to disable auto indentation, all the solutions have to do with editing the init.el file, but I do not have such a file. I have a 'ediff-init.el' and a 'viper-init.el' file, and making the changes to them have not given me any results.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it Prolog mode? You can add instructions at the top of the file to set the Emacs mode. Also, you can give commands directly in Emacs, they don't have to be in the init file.

Comment: You have to disable electric indent mode. See this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5941) .

Comment: `~/.emacs.d/init.el` may also be called `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.el`.

Comment: Also make sure your buffer is running in `prolog-mode` (`Prolog` or similar should be listed in the modeline, otherwise you can use `C-h m` and it should be listed there).  Incorrect indentation is often a sign of running the wrong major mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable auto indent globally in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390238/disable-auto-indent-globally-in-emacs)